# How to integrate Twig template using Code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I tried to implement to Twig template into code igniter using this [link to twig basics](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#basics).

This is my code:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'path/to/Twig/Autoloader.php');
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array('index' => 'Hello {{ name }}!'));
$twig =new Twig_Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render('index', array('name' =>'Testing Twig'));
```

It giving output :

```
Hello Testing Twig!
```

But I am unable to find the templates folder in code igniter.,

can anyone help me out?

Comment: well you will need to implement your own mechanism for file loader. CI does not support twig out of the box. What you can do is, override view loader and have it render views using twig

Comment: Sorry @Broncha Iam not getting you, can you say in detail, where should I override?

Comment: Have you used the Sparks Repo before?
http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/

Comment: I tried the Integration of that github Even though its not coming @philip, No error but didnot get required output

Answer (score 2):

The best and simplier I know is this:

Start by including twig to your project using composer (which will keep it up to date) :

```
composer require "twig/twig:^2.0"
```

Then, create the file `application/libraries/Twig.php` (capitalization is important) containing:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');

class Twig {
    private $twig;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(APPPATH . 'views');
        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    }

    public function render($template, $placeholders)
    {
        return $this->twig->render($template . '.php', $placeholders);
    }
}
```

Lastly, use it in a controller like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('twig'); // Can also be autoloaded
    echo $this->twig->render('some_page_in_views', ['foo' => 'barr']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already made the library for linkage between twig and ci.

You can see the link below

> https://github.com/bmatschullat/Twig-Codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of projects that integrate Twig in CodeIgniter.

Here are a few of them (by CodeIgniter version):

- CI 2.x:

  - http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/
  - https://github.com/dilantha/codeigniter-twig
- CI 3.x:

  - https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig
  - https://github.com/davidsosavaldes/Attire

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method inside a controller which renders a template with Twig.

```
public function some_method () {

    $ci_path = realpath(FCPATH);

    Twig_Autoloader::register();

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($ci_path.'/application/views');

    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => $ci_path.'/application/views_twig_cache',
    ));                

    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('twigtest.php');

    echo $template->render(['name'=>'Jhon']);

}
```

Probably what you need to do is to set Twig_Loader_Filesystem to the correct path. Note that I also set the cache path... if you unset this your template will regerate each page load.

I'm doing the autoloading with the composer autoload (see the config/config.php inside application folder). I have composer.json inside application/vendor.

Hope that helps.